# Return file with list of databases in mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

Is there a way that I can output a list of all databases into a file. I know that you can use the `SHOW DATABASES;` command to return the databases but that is **not** in the correct format:

```
+-------------------------+
| Database                |
+-------------------------+
| information_schema      |
| abcd                    |
| mysql                   |
| performance_schema      |
| stathisK_travelbox      |
+-------------------------+
```

I want a file like:

```
information_schema 
abcd 
mysql 
performance_schema 
stathisK_travelbox
```

Comment: In which operating system, you are getting this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have done:

```
SQL="SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata"

mysql -u root -p -ANe"${SQL}" > /listofdatabases.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo mysql -u username -p -e "show databases" > /tmp/output.txt
```

> your output file must have write permission